# SagePay V3 issues with Billing and Iframe

Tags: opayo, omnipay

I would like some advice and a little help.

A recent project I have been working one had its version of SagePay upgrade to use the version 3 protocol.  The side of effects of this meant that users are no longer able to edit their billing address details.  The previous protocol v2.23 did allow this in low profile mode and in normal mode.

Further more from what I have understood in the new protocol, iFrames are no longer being supported.

I have read the documentation which suggests downloading the custom templates (Card_Details.xslt and Card_Details_Low.xslt), customising them and sending over to SagePay in order to add these to the system.  But I am unable to find any instructions on how to achieve this.

How I allow the customer to have the ability to change the billing address?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the template you are using (in My Sage Pay) to Default. That should set things back to how they were.

FYI - iframe integration is still supported in v3.00